# Having problems with nested for loop in Java and JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, servlets

I would like to have a JSON output having "postCode" as "parent", and its child would be the "statusName" and "statusCount".

```
JSONObject jsonObject = New JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = New JSONArray();

for (StatisticsDTO object : lstDTO) {

    jsonObject.put("postCode",object.getPostalCode());
    log.info(object.getPostalCode());


    List <StatisticsDetailsDTO> listStat = object.getStatistics();  

    //log.info("listStat" : + listStat.size()); // Assuming that I have 2 postal codes.

    if (listStat != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i< listStat.size(); i++) {
            StatisticsDetailsDTO dtostat = listStat.get(i); 

            jsonObject.put("statusName",dtostat.getStatName());
            jsonObject.put("statusCount",dtostat.getStatCount());

            jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
            log.info(jsonArray.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

The output is:

 12345

[{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"}] 

[{"statusName":"Test2","statusCount":"2"},{"statusName":"Test2","statusCount":"2"}]

[{"statusName":"Test3","statusCount":"3"},{"statusName":"Test3","statusCount":"3",{"statusName":"Test3","statusCount":"3"}]

 67890

[{"statusName":"Test4","statusCount":"4"},{"statusName":"Test4","statusCount":"4"},{"statusName":"Test4","statusCount":"4"},{"statusName":"Test4","statusCount":"4"}] 

[{"statusName":"Test5","statusCount":"5"},{"statusName":"Test5","statusCount":"5"},{"statusName":"Test5","statusCount":"5"},{"statusName":"Test5","statusCount":"5"},{"statusName":"Test5","statusCount":"5"}]

[{"statusName":"Test6","statusCount":"6"},{"statusName":"Test6","statusCount":"6",{"statusName":"Test6","statusCount":"6"},{"statusName":"Test6","statusCount":"6"},{"statusName":"Test6","statusCount":"6"},{"statusName":"Test6","statusCount":"6"},{"statusName":"Test6","statusCount":"6"}]

The result should be something like the one below but in JSON format. I noticed that the value gets repeated.

Postal Code : 12345

- Status Name: Test1 Status Count: 1
- Status Name: Test2 Status Count: 2
- Status Name: Test3 Status Count: 3

Postal Code: 67890

- Status Name: Test4 Status Count: 4
- Status Name: Test5 Status Count: 5
- Status Name: Test6 Status Count: 6

Answer (score 0):

You should create `jsonObject` in each iteration in order to avoid repeating values.

Check this code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = New JSONArray();

for (StatisticsDTO object : lstDTO) {

    JSONObject jsonObject = New JSONObject(); //Move it here
    jsonObject.put("postCode",object.getPostalCode());
    log.info(object.getPostalCode());


    List <StatisticsDetailsDTO> listStat = object.getStatistics();  

    //log.info("listStat" : + listStat.size()); // Assuming that I have 2 postal codes.
    JSONArray tempJsonArray = New JSONArray();
    if (listStat != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i< listStat.size(); i++) {
            StatisticsDetailsDTO dtostat = listStat.get(i); 

            jsonObject.put("statusName",dtostat.getStatName());
            jsonObject.put("statusCount",dtostat.getStatCount());

            jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
            tempJsonArray.add(jsonObject);
        }   
    }    
    log.info(tmepJsonArray.toString());
   }
```

Comment: Hi, it now shows something like this:

12345 
[{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"}] 
[{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"},{"statusName":"Test2","statusCount":"2"}] 
[{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"},{"statusName":"Test2","statusCount":"2"},{"statusName":"Test3","statusCount":"3"}]

Comment: try now. I changed logging.

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: can you post data you are seeing?

Comment: `12345 
[{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"}] [{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"},{"statusName":"Test2","statusCount":"2"}] [{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"},{"statusName":"Test2","statusCount":"2"},{"statusName":"Test3","statusCount":"3"}]`

Comment: It somehow iterates. What I need is the last element of the array (complete one) shown below.

`12345 
[{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"},{"statusName":"Test2","statusCount":"2"},{"statusName":"Test3","statusCount":"3"}]`

Comment: can you post the output of the my implementation?

Comment: This one:

`12345 [{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"}] [{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"},{"statusName":"Test2","statusCount":"2"}] [{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"},{"statusName":"Test2","statusCount":"2"},{"statusName":"Test3","statusCount":"3"}]`

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the late reply. I am now getting: `12345 [{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"}] `

It is not getting the Test2, Test3.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the late reply. I am now getting: `12345 [{"statusName":"Test1","statusCount":"1"}] '

It is not getting the Test2, Test3.

Comment: can you add more logging. I have to see what are you receiving from database?